# GridSearchCV on DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm trying to run a `GridSearchCV` over a `DecisionTreeClassifier`, with the only hyper-parameter being `max_depth`. The two versions I ran this with are:

```
max_depth = range(1,20)
```

The `best_estimator_ attribute` shows a max_depth of 15 while the scoring function shows 0.8880 on the test set

```
max_depth = range(1,15)
```

The `best_estimator_ attribute` shows a max_depth of 10 with a higher score of 0.8907.

My question is, why doesn't `GridSearchCV` pick a max_depth of 10 the first time around if it gives a better score?

The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=7)

parameters = {"max_depth": range(1,20), "random_state":[7]}

scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score,beta=0.5)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_grid=parameters,scoring=scorer)

grid_fit =grid_obj.fit(X_train,y_train)

best_clf = grid_fit.best_estimator_

predictions = (clf.fit(X_train, y_train)).predict(X_test)
best_predictions = best_clf.predict(X_test)

# Report the before-and-afterscores
print best_clf

print "\nOptimized Model\n------"
print "Final accuracy score on the testing data: 
{:.4f}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, best_predictions))
print "Final F-score on the testing data: {:.4f}".format(fbeta_score(y_test, 
best_predictions, beta = 0.5))
```

Comment: Did you just delete the other question and re-add it, throwing away the comments?

Comment: I did. There wasn't anything to "throw away" other than two comments asking me to add code, which I did.

Comment: So you removed it to make i look like you did prepared something within your question? And again you present code without reproducable ```X_train, y_train```.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Question**

> Why doesn't GridSearchCV pick a max_depth of 10 the first time around
>   if it gives a better score?

**My Answer (as I understand it, that I've acquired through too many past sources to cite)**

The deeper the tree goes, the more intricacies about the training data it learns. This is called "overfitting" where it learns the training data really well but might not generalize well on unseen data. **Why is the default hyperparameter** `max_depth=3` ? That is a design decision by the sklearn team.

**But why `max_depth=3`?**

The developers probably determine this by considering a default value that is applicable to most use-cases. They also might have determined that 3 generalizes better on unseen data.

**Decision trees are random**

You won't get the same `best_estimator_` every time you re-run. Try using `random_state` to make it repeatable each time.